# Google Vision API Requests from IP address ... are blocked

Tags: php, ocr, google-vision

I using Google Vision OCR to get text from image with PHP language.
When i used in a long time. I get error below:

```
array(1) {
  ["error"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["code"]=>
    int(403)
    ["message"]=>
    string(53) "Requests from IP address ..... are blocked."
    ["status"]=>
    string(17) "PERMISSION_DENIED"
    ["details"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["@type"]=>
        string(35) "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help"
        ["links"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          array(2) {
            ["description"]=>
            string(32) "Google developer console API key"
            ["url"]=>
            string(75) "https://console.developers.google.com/project/191619933224/apiui/credential"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please show me reason and how to fix it.
Thank all so much.

Comment: probably you have exceeded your request limit quota and the ip can no longer send requests. You either need to raise the limit or handle requests better.

Comment: Hi, are you still using google vision ocr with php?

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have authorized the API in the [Cloud API console](https://console.cloud.google.com) and configured your PHP client as described in the [sample documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/vision/api).

Specifically, make sure you download the `credentials.json` file that is associated with your vision API project and set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to the credential path before running the sample.